# @Url.Action in the View SOMETIMES doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view I have something like the following

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new {param1 = ViewBag.Param1, page = ViewBag.Page })" alt="" />
```

This works some of the time. However, every now and then the image just doesn't load. I set a breakpoint in the GetImage ActionResult and when the image isn't loading, the breakpoint isn't being hit.

This behavior seems to be completely random, if I just refresh the page over and over sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: please show your code and explain what you want to ask ?

Comment: Sorry, code wasn't showing. Hopefully the question should be self explanatory now.

Comment: When the image does not render, Check the view source of the page and make sure that url for the image source is valid (the parameter values).

Comment: @DavidSpence sorry, I'm not actually sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Shyju Can confirm everything is valid, additionally if I copy that Url into a new tab I get the image

Comment: Interesting !  I Would look into the `GetImage` closely then.

Comment: If your refresh the img URL does it behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

view :

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage",new {name="google.png"})" alt="" />
```

and controller action look like below

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public FileResult GetImage(string name)
{
     var path = @"C:\VS2015\Images\" + name;
     return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open),"image/jpeg");
}
```

Hope your controller action code look like above.
it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

(Should be a comment but too long...)

Before you start diagnosing server-side issues, find out what the actual problem is.

Open up the browser developer tools (F12 on win), switch to the Network tab and keep refreshing until the problem occurs. (Note: there's a setting to disable the browser cache when dev tools are open, make sure to uncheck it to replicate the situation accurately)

When the problem occurs, scroll down to the request for the image and check if ti was fetched from the server or the local cache. If from the server, there should be a status code which will give you a hint (404/500) and the response body may contain useful information (like a full stack trace if your server is configured to show errors). At the very least, a server response means that a connection was made and that there should be some useful information in server logs.

It's also possible the problem is with either the browser cache or a proxy between the client and server.

Finally, if it is a problem server-side and you can't see error details in the browser, have a rummage through the servers event logs. All .Net errors are recorded there (by default at least).

Once you've got more information on what's causing the problem, edit your question and we can go from there.